# Whmcs - Custom affiliate links

Tags: php, redirect, whmcs, affiliate

I joined an affiliate system ([whmcs](http://www.whmcs.com/)) and I received a affiliate url:

```
https://www.example.com/client/aff.php?aff=xxx
```

The thing is that this link redirects me to the company homepage but I don't want this. I want to redirect to custom pages. Is this possible in some way?

At a first view I guess that you can do some handwork in the aff.php file and use the url like this:

```
https://www.example.com/client/aff.php?aff=xxx&url=https://www.example.com/othersection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours, I managed to find a solution for this. Using the lastest version of whmcs 7.0.2 inside aff.php, at the bottom of the file **just before**:

```
// perform redirect
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$whmcs->get_config('Domain'),true,301);
```

> https://www.example.com/client/aff.php?aff=xxx&url=othersection

I've added this code for relative url's:

```
if ($whmcs->get_req_var('url')) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: ".$whmcs->get_config('Domain')."/".$whmcs->get_req_var('url'),true,301);
  die();
}
```

or this code for absolute url's:

```
if ($whmcs->get_req_var('url')) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: ".$whmcs->get_req_var('url'),true,301);
  die();
}
```

> https://www.example.com/client/aff.php?aff=xxx&url=https://www.example.com/othersection

<sup>It seems that this code is available for version 6.2.2 - 6.3.1 - 7.0.2 - 7.1.0</sup>